# Perform click event without clicking android listview

Tags: android

I have a small module to list folder structure in android. if user clicks one node (this node is a collection of icons. ie. folder icon, arrow icons etc) it lists the sub folders in that selected folder. Now I want to show the sub folders of the root folder at the very beginning. Existing one only shows the root folder. I can do this easily if I can call the click listener of the node item in the very beginning. How can I do it.

```
public static void callFolderSection(Context context,int mailBox,Fragment fragment)
{
    AndroidTreeView tView;
    //selectedMailBox = mailBox;
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dashContext = context;
    fragmentName = fragment;
    selectedMailBox = mailBox;

    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_default);
    ((DashboardActivity) context).dialogFolder = dialog;
    ViewGroup containerView = (ViewGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.container);

    MailServices mailServices = new MailServices();
    ArrayList<FolderSection> folderSectionList ;
    folderSectionList = mailServices.listFoldersAndSections("0",mailBox);
```

//Get the root folder

```
    TreeNode root = TreeNode.root();
    TreeNode computerRoot = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(GlobalVariables.getGsLoginProjectNo(),"0","0",fragment,0,0,folderSectionList.get(0).get_childCount()));
    for (int count = 0;count < folderSectionList.size();count++)
    {
        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(folderSectionList.get(count).get_title(),Integer.toString(folderSectionList.get(count).get_int_Key()),Integer.toString(folderSectionList.get(count).get_int_parent()),fragmentName,folderSectionList.get(count).get_isSmartSection(),folderSectionList.get(count).get_itemCount(),folderSectionList.get(count).get_childCount()));
        computerRoot.addChildren(treeNode);
    }

    root.addChildren(computerRoot);

    tView = new AndroidTreeView(context, root);
    tView.setDefaultAnimation(true);
    tView.setDefaultContainerStyle(R.style.TreeNodeStyleCustom);
    tView.setDefaultViewHolder(IconTreeItemHolder.class);
```

//Set the click listener

```
    tView.setDefaultNodeClickListener(nodeClickListener);

    containerView.addView(tView.getView());

    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    if (GlobalVariables.getGsDevice().equals("tab")) {


    dialog.show();

}
```

//Click listener

```
 private  static TreeNode.TreeNodeClickListener nodeClickListener = new TreeNode.TreeNodeClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(TreeNode node, Object value) {
        IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem item = (IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem) value;
        ((DashboardActivity) dashContext).folderIntKey = Integer.parseInt(item.int_Key);

        MailServices mailServices = new MailServices();
        DocumentServices documentServices = new DocumentServices();

        try {


            if (Integer.parseInt(item.int_Key) != 0) {
                if (node.getChildren().size() == 0) {

                    ArrayList<FolderSection> folderSectionList;
                    if(((DashboardActivity) dashContext).isFolderDoc)
                    {
                        folderSectionList = documentServices.listFoldersAndSections(item.int_Key);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                         folderSectionList = mailServices.listFoldersAndSections(item.int_Key, selectedMailBox);

                    }

                    for (int count = 0; count < folderSectionList.size(); count++) {
                        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode(new IconTreeItemHolder.IconTreeItem(folderSectionList.get(count).get_title(), Integer.toString(folderSectionList.get(count).get_int_Key()), Integer.toString(folderSectionList.get(count).get_int_parent()), fragmentName,folderSectionList.get(count).get_isSmartSection(),folderSectionList.get(count).get_itemCount(),folderSectionList.get(count).get_childCount()));
                        node.addChildren(treeNode);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
};
```

**EDIT:** Edited the code snipets to work in a propper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
nodeClickListener.onClick(node,value);
```

Node=The node you want.
Value=The value it has.

**EDIT:** I read the code of the library and maybe you can use

```
expandNode(TreeNode node)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **performClick()** method.

As you have root view.